# Proof of the limit of product of sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, epsilon-delta

I am trying to prove

> if $\left\{a_n\right\}$ and $\left\{b_n\right\}$ are two sequences such that $a_n \to a$ and $b_n \to b$, then $a_nb_n \to ab$

I already know the proof using boundedness. But i tried in this way.

Using the fact that
$$a_{n} b_{n}-a b=\left(a_{n}-a\right)\left(b_{n}-b\right)+a\left(b_{n}-b\right)+b\left(a_{n}-a\right)$$
We get
$$|a_nb_n-ab|\leq |a_n-a||b_n-b|+|a||b_n-b|+|b||a_n-a|\to (1)$$
Now since $a_n,b_n$ are convergent, we have for every $\epsilon_1 >0$, $\exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n \geq n_0$
$$|a_n-a|<\epsilon_1 \to (2)$$
Like-wise for every $\epsilon_2>0$,
$\exists n_0' \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n \geq n_0'$
$$|b_n-b|<\epsilon_2 \to (3)$$
Using $(2),(3)$ in $(1)$ with $\Delta$ inequality we get
$$|a_nb_n-ab|<\epsilon_1\epsilon_2+|a|\epsilon_2+|b|\epsilon_1$$
whenever $n \geq max(n_0,n_0')$

Now how to conclude?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good time to use a trick from analysis.  You have all the epsilons, just have to show they go to zero.  This is where you left off:
$$|a_nb_n-ab|<\epsilon_1\epsilon_2+|a|\epsilon_2+|b|\epsilon_1$$
whenever $n \geq max(n_0,n_0')$

We have to first define an arbitrary a 'master' epsilon, $\epsilon$.  Then we lower $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ as far as we need to get the total under $\epsilon$.  (We can lower them as far as we want because they are arbitrarily small.)

For any $\epsilon >0$ we can choose $\epsilon_1 <  \min{(1, \  \frac{\epsilon}{3|b|}, \  \epsilon)}$, and $\epsilon_2 <  \min{(1, \  \frac{\epsilon}{3|a|}, \  \epsilon)}$.  Now $$|a_nb_n-ab|<\epsilon_1\epsilon_2+|a|\epsilon_2+|b|\epsilon_1 < \frac{\epsilon}{3} +\frac{\epsilon}{3}+\frac{\epsilon}{3} = \epsilon$$.

So $|a_nb_n-ab| \rightarrow 0$ and we arrive at $a_nb_n \rightarrow ab$